# The example code for two way bindings on emberjs.com doesn't work

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

I typed the following code on "documentation" page on emberjs.com
http://emberjs.com/documentation/

But, it does not show the result that I expect.
Why is that?

```
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

console.log(App.husband.get('householdIncome')); //it shows 80000

App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);

**console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome')); // it shows 80000 not 90000**
console.log(App.husband.get('householdIncome')); // this shows 90000
```

I'm expecting to get 90000 when I type console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome'));,
as the example code on ember.js says.

Does anyone know what's wrong?
Please give me a help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that same documentation:

> Note that bindings don't update immediately. Ember waits until all of your application code has finished running before synchronizing changes, so you can change a bound property as many times as you'd like without worrying about the overhead of syncing bindings when values are transient.

You can wrap your console.log statements with [Ember.Run.next](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next) to make sure the binding updates are applied before they run.

```
App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);

Ember.run.next(function() {
  console.log("her income: " + App.wife.get('householdIncome')); // it shows 90000
  console.log("his income: " + App.husband.get('householdIncome')); // it also shows 90000
});​
```

Comment: I read the sentence starting with "Note that bindings don't update immediately.". But,I didn't understand what it meant. Now, I got it! Thank you very much!!!